# Body is json but request->get() return null

Tags: php, laravel, post, laravel-5, postman

I posted an object from postman to controller with Laravel 5.2 but when i want to get an field with `$request->get('receiver_name')` response return null

postman screen shot :

[image]

Comment: Try to do `$request->get('receiver_name')`?

Comment: yes i used `$request->get('receiver_name')`

Comment: please help me friends

Comment: try doing a $request->all() and see if there's anything?

Comment: still shows `[]` :(

Comment: Did you import the right Request (`use Illuminate\Http\Request;`) ?

Comment: yes namespace added

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136629/discussion-between-amirali-and-sted).

Comment: Please post as form-data

Comment: Post the output of `dd($request->all())`

Comment: `dd($request->all())` returned `[]` my friend :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the value of the field "receiver_cell_phone" which is invalid, because it is a number starting with a zero.

In short, in JSON leading zeros are not supporting.
If you have a field that may have leading zeros, treat it as a string.

Change your post field to:

```
"receiver_cell_phone": "0983242342"
```